# AngularJS resource with getter in params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, typescript, resources

I'm trying to access an API with `angularResource.get(params)`

The model for the class looks like this:

```
export class d_stp_searchbar implements Id_stp_searchbar {

    lperiode?: number;
    private _lsichtweise: number;
    scode?: string;
    sbezeichnung?: string;
    bezeichnungLabel: string;

    set lsichtweise(value) {
        this._lsichtweise = value;
        this.bezeichnungLabel = this.lsichtweise === 5 ? "Name" : "Bezeichnung";
    }

    get lsichtweise() {
        return this._lsichtweise;
    }

    public bezeichnung() {
        if (this.lsichtweise === 5) {
            this.bezeichnungLabel = "Name";
        } else {
            this.bezeichnungLabel = "Bezeichnung";
        }
    }
}
```

The function, where i call the api looks like the following:

```
searchStundenplan(params: d_stp_searchbar): angular.IPromise<any> {
    this.searchStundenplanParams = params;
    this.localStorageService.set("searchStundenplanParams", this.searchStundenplanParams);

    return this.searchStundenplanResource.get(params)
        .$promise.then((result) => {
            this.searchStundenplanResult = result;
            this.searchStundenplanResultChangedNotify();
        });
 }
```

The problem I'am facing is, that the URL that will be called looks like this:

`GET /api/search/Stundenplan?_lsichtweise=1&bezeichnungLabel=Bezeichnung&lperiode=86`

but I want, that instead of `_lsichtweise` `lsichtweise` will be used.

Do I use it wrong or does somebody know, why not the public property `lsichtweise` is used?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: There is no public property `lsichtweise` in your class `d_stp_searchbar`. You created a magic function `get` but `angular.IPromise` does only recognize class vars and ignores the magic getter function. Just add a public class property `lsichtweise: number;`. Maybe `angular.IPromise` will call the magic getter function and you will be fine.

Comment: An other attemp is to remap your model attributes while they are parsed as params into `angular.IPromise`. Which solution you would prefer?

Comment: The problem was, that the `d_stp_searchbar` was only instantiated properly the first time we called it. So your comment was not the solution, but a gamechanger for further investigations. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please post your solution for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by myself:

The problem was, that the d_stp_searchbar was only instantiated properly the first time we called it.

We were loading a JSON into a TypeScript object like this:

```
this.searchParamsStundenplan = localStorageService.get("searchParamsStundenplan") as d_stp_searchbar;
```

but then the `searchParamsStundenplan` does not contain the (in the question mentioned) `lsichtweise` getter and setter because it was a plain data object without any functions.

So we had to create an instance the following way:

```
let searchParamsStundenplanTemp = new d_stp_searchbar();
searchParamsStundenplanTemp.bindinglsichtweise = this.searchParamsStundenplan.bindinglsichtweise;
searchParamsStundenplanTemp.lperiode = this.searchParamsStundenplan.lperiode;
searchParamsStundenplanTemp.scode = this.searchParamsStundenplan.scode;
this.searchParamsStundenplan = searchParamsStundenplanTemp;
```

This way it worked.